# Zsh - History "up arrow" only searches from beginning of previous command, not working for middle

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

For example, if I have a command in the past like `cd ~/dir` I am not able to find it by entering with `dir` then pressing the "up" arrow.

This is for zsh with oh-my-zsh. What I've tried that hasn't worked:

- zsh-autosuggestions plugin, with and without `bindkey "^[[A" history-substring-search-up bindkey "^[[B" history-substring-search-down` in the .zshrc
- zsh-history-substring-search

Any thoughts on getting history search to work for middle of commands?

Comment: “in the .zshrc” Please provide more context on what’s in your `.zshrc` and where in there/how you tried to set it.